# Prebuild entity framework migration for deployment

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

Currently, I run the migration using

```sh
dotnet ef database update
```

To do this, I have to source code with deployed to it will be able to build the project:

Example output:

```
Build started...
...
```

Is there a way to run the migrations using the project binary which I prebuild in the ci/cd process?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the `--no-build` flag. For more information, see the cli reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#common-options).